# Parse Name and Phone Numbers From String

Tags: php, regex, string

I have to convert plain text order forms (which I have no control over) into individual database fields.

As part of this, I get 2 variations on this part of the order, for which I need the Name, Mobile (Cell), and Landline (if provided). The text comes in like this:

```
FirstName1 Surname1 on 0412 555 555 or 9555 55555 ,  FirstName2 Surname2 on 0555 555 555 or
```

or it may come in with only Mobile (Cell) for 1 of them like

```
FirstName1 Surname1 on 0412 555 555 ,  FirstName2 Surname2 on 0555 555 555 or
```

(NOTE that the final 'or' is not a mistake, that's how it's received).

What's the best way of dealing with this? Exploding by the comma and then explode by ' or ' to see if there's more than 1 phone?

Regex is not my strength hence explode suggestion, but suggestions happily taken.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use explode and split like this :

```
$lines = array('FirstName1 Surname1 on 0412 555 555 or 9555 55555 ,  FirstName2 Surname2 on 0555 555 555 or ','FirstName1 Surname1 on 0412 555 555 ,  FirstName2 Surname2 on 0555 555 555 or ');

foreach($lines as $line) {
  $persons = explode(',', $line);
  foreach($persons as $person) {
    $infos = preg_split('/on|or/', $person);
    echo "name : ",$infos[0],"\n";
    echo "phone1 : ",$infos[1],"\n";
    if (isset($infos[2])) echo "phone2 : ",$infos[2],"\n";
  }
}
```

**output:**

```
name : FirstName1 Surname1
phone1 :  0412 555 555
phone2 :  9555 55555
name :   FirstName2 Surname2
phone1 :  0555 555 555
phone2 :
name : FirstName1 Surname1
phone1 :  0412 555 555
name :   FirstName2 Surname2
phone1 :  0555 555 555
phone2 :
```

Comment: I think I like this solution better than the plain regex as it means just 1 pass to deal with the various combinations rather than multiple search patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script using regex sub-patterns for the fields you need:

```
<?php

// FirstName1 Surname1 on 0412 555 555 or 9555 55555 ,  FirstName2 Surname2 on 0555 555 555 or
define('P1_NAME_1',1);
define('P1_MOBILE_1',2);
define('P1_LANDLINE_1',3);
define('P1_NAME_2',4);
define('P1_MOBILE_2',5);

$p1='/^([A-Za-z- ]+) on ([0-9]{4} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}) or ([0-9]{4} [0-9]{5}) , ([A-Za-z- ]+) on ([0-9]{4} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}) or/';
$s1="Foo Bar-Baz on 0412 555 555 or 9555 55555 , Do Rae Me on 0555 555 555 or";
$m1=array();
$n1=preg_match($p1,$s1,$m1);
echo "PATTERN 1:  Mobile and Landline provided\n";
echo "Name 1: ".$m1[P1_NAME_1]."\n";
echo "Mobile 1: ".$m1[P1_MOBILE_1]."\n";
echo "Landline 1: ".$m1[P1_LANDLINE_1]."\n";
echo "Name 2: ".$m1[P1_NAME_2]."\n";
echo "Mobile 2: ".$m1[P1_MOBILE_2]."\n";
echo "\n";


// FirstName1 Surname1 on 0412 555 555 ,  FirstName2 Surname2 on 0555 555 555 or
define('P2_NAME_1',1);
define('P2_MOBILE_1',2);
define('P2_NAME_2',3);
define('P2_MOBILE_2',4);

$p2='/^([A-Za-z- ]+) on ([0-9]{4} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}) , ([A-Za-z- ]+) on ([0-9]{4} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}) or/';
$s2="Foo Bar-Baz on 0412 555 555 , Do Rae Me on 0555 555 555 or";
$m2=array();
$n2=preg_match($p2,$s2,$m2);
echo "PATTERN 2:  Mobile only provided\n";
echo "Name 1: ".$m2[P2_NAME_1]."\n";
echo "Mobile 1: ".$m2[P2_MOBILE_1]."\n";
echo "Name 2: ".$m2[P2_NAME_2]."\n";
echo "Mobile 2: ".$m2[P2_MOBILE_2]."\n";
?>
```

You'll need to adapt the character classes used for the name fields to include **all possible/legal** characters allowed.  Phone numbers are a bit more predictable, though watch for variations on spaces, no spaces, and hyphens.

Comment: So I really need to make multiple passes to ensure I capture all possibilities (which I just found out also includes another variation). I'm thinking that a mixture of explode using ',' as a delimiter and your regex would solve it as although there are variations on the patterns, the are NOT free entry text and do follow a format.